# Django test error: Column does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql

`Postgresql`, `Django 2.0`, `Python 3.6.4`

After running a migration that changed the name of a field `desktop_pay` to simply `pay`, I'm getting an error when running `manage.py test` saying the column `pay` does not exist.

Here's the migration:

```
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('instructions', '0055_auto_20180517_1508'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='instruction',
            old_name='desktop_pay',
            new_name='pay',
        ),
    ]
```

Here's the error:

```
> python .\manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column instructions_instruction.pay does not exist
LINE 1: "...on"."quota", "instructions_instruction"."target", "instructi...
                                                              ^
```

If I start a psql prompt, though, I can clearly see that the column does exist, at least in the "real" table.

```
mydatabase=> \d+ instructions_instruction
                                                              Table "public.instructions_instruction"
       Column        |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |                       Default                        | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                  | integer                |           | not null | nextval('instructions_instruction_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 quota               | smallint               |           | not null |                                                      | plain    |              |
 pay                 | numeric(5,2)           |           | not null |                                                      | main     |              |

### etc...
```

What's going on here? Why is Django not finding the column? How can I debug this?

Comment: Are you sure you connected to the correct database? (I know that's a stupid error, but somehow that happens occasionally).

Comment: Heh fair question, but yes. I'm connecting to the database I have defined in `settings.py`.

Comment: Is any of test code using models old field name? Or Any derived class of model?

Comment: No, the only place the old field name `desktop_pay` appears in my code is in older migrations.

Comment: you tried changing instance via django admin, if it throws the same error ?

Comment: I hadn't but I just did try that and no error was thrown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've run into these 'column does not exist' errors when my migrations somehow got messed up, sometimes this has happened when I accidentally deleted/overwrote migrations, but I've also had it happen just by running typical migrations which I can't really explain.

So I would guess you would have to pinpoint the problem in your migrations. What worked for me was, after confirming my schema was in fact as I wanted to be, resetting migrations with the help of Scenario #2 [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html).

Comment: This did it. So that this will (hopefully) work in production, I had to check out my master branch, reset migrations using the link you provided, merge master into my development branch, then migrate the new changes.

Comment: My production server is happy with this solution as well.

Answer (score 11):

I've faced this problem too. First of all, I couldn't got why this errors only appears while testing.

Then I looked into traceback and saw that Django fails to run one of my migration not related to column Django can't find.

It was manually written migration to populate objects `uuid` field with autogenerated values. I import model `Post` just as usual.

```
import uuid
from django.db import migrations

from posts.models import Post


def gen_uuid(apps, schema_editor):
    for post in Post.objects.all():
        post.uuid = uuid.uuid4()
        post.save(update_fields=["uuid"])


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("posts", "0014_post_uuid"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(gen_uuid, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),
    ]
```

I don't clearly understand why, but this code breaks migrations while preparing testing database (and works fine outside of testing mode). So any following migrations do not apply to testing database and that cause `column does not exist` error.

So what to do? Use `apps.get_model` instead of it as described in official Django docs on writing migrations https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields.

Something like this.

```
import uuid
from django.db import migrations
    
def gen_uuid(apps, schema_editor):
    Post = apps.get_model("posts", "Post")
    for post in Post.objects.all():
        post.uuid = uuid.uuid4()
        post.save(update_fields=["uuid"])
```